# Is there a way to compare enum type only and ignore its associated value?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Currently, we have the following enum.

```
enum Animal : Equatable {
    case dog(String)
    case cat(Int)
}
```

If we want to compare enum type and its associate value, we can simply do this.

```
let dog0 = Animal.dog("mimi")
let dog1 = Animal.dog("hihi")

if (dog0 == dog1) {
    print("same dog type and same name")
} else {
    print("not same dog")
}
```

*not same dog* will be printed.

What if, we also want to have the ability, to compare enum type only and ignore its associated value?

```
if (???) {
    print("same dog type (might be different name)")
} else {
    print("not same dog")
}
```

May I know, what kind of technique we can use?

Comment: You could add a computed variable called `typeID` which returns an `Int`. This computed variable could return the same number for the same type ignoring the associated value. Then you could simply check `dog0.typeID == dog1.typeID`